# How to change row names based on group in R?

Tags: r, row, rename

I have a data frame with 4 columns, one of which is state. Several rows have the same state, as shown below:
[image: have the same state]

I would like to rename the rows based on the state name. As seen in the picture, I would like rows 1-15 to be named texas.

I've tried the following line `rownames(stateSales2) <- stateSales$state`
but I get the error and warning message

```
Error in row.names<-.data.frame(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘alabama’, ‘alaska’, ‘arizona’, ‘arkansas’, ‘california’, ‘colorado’, ‘connecticut’, ‘delaware’, ‘florida’, ‘georgia’, ‘hawaii’, ‘idaho’, ‘illinois’, ‘indiana’, ‘iowa’, ‘kansas’, ‘kentucky’, ‘louisiana’, ‘maine’, ‘maryland’, ‘massachusetts’, ‘michigan’, ‘minnesota’, ‘mississippi’, ‘missouri’, ‘montana’, ‘nebraska’, ‘nevada’, ‘new hampshire’, ‘new jersey’, ‘new mexico’, ‘new york’, ‘north carolina’, ‘north dakota’, ‘ohio’, ‘oklahoma’, ‘oregon’, ‘pennsylvania’, ‘rhode island’, ‘south carolina’, ‘south dakota’, ‘tennessee’, ‘texas’, ‘utah’, ‘vermont’, ‘virginia’, ‘washington’, ‘west virginia’, ‘wisconsin’, ‘wyoming’
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error is clear: all row names must be perfectly unique. If you want `"texas"` somewhere in it, see `make.unique(rep('a',5))`.

Comment: the error message is politely suggesting that some things are both sub-optimal and not preferred. But consider, why would you want to do it when you have a perfectly good column that by row tells you the same thing? And in the future, when you want row 4, it will be easier to say gimme row 4 than row texas, er, texas texas er, gimme all of texas and I'll fgfure it out.

Comment: cpersonal, the use of row names is definitely a preference-thing, but something to keep in mind: many operations (namely `dplyr` and other `tibble`-using functions) on `data.frame`s will wipe them. (I don't know of anything that strictly requires row names.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have duplicate row names. That's what the error message means when it says "`duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`".

> I would like rows 1-15 to be named `texas`.

You can't do that, that would introduce duplicate row names.